# How to fetch List of Street names in india using php/html

Tags: php, search-engine

I'm doing a local search engine like justdial. I'm trying to show the street names when user types in text ( data ) field. Do I need to store all street names in database for this. I searched for street name lists in google, that also I'm not getting. How can I fetch the street name when user types. 
For example: when user type 'Koramangala' , drop down should show 'Koramangala 1st block,Koramangala 2nd block', etc..... Please help. I'm sorry if this topic is out of stackoverflow terms & conditions. I'm stuck with this. That's why. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, otherwise you fetch data from some third party source which gives you all the list of block of  'Koramangala'

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp. refer the link or simply use ajax script helpfull to search and get the data's  real time  from database. Real time php ajax calling refer they link http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp?.

Comment: I know about datalist, and have been using it. But the problem is, how can I get the street names. I didn't find any third party sources for getting street names. Could you please suggest one?